# Views -- failed to override default templates despite being bold in "theming info"

Tags: views, theming

I just created a new template for my view with the most specifically name. The template itself can be displayed as bold in "theming info".

However, it fails to override the original template, I can even see the content of the later ones by clicking "Display output" or "Style output" at "Page: Theming information". Any changes I've done to the original files can be successfully reflected in "theme info" while my newer customized templates seems to be ignored.

Comment: You cleared the caches right?

Comment: Either clear theme registry (one of caches, so clearing all caches should do), or look for something like this in views issue queue. What's that template for? Row?